# Issues with my criteria query when calling SQL created function

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa-2.0, hibernate-4.x

In my *Postgres* 9.1 database I have a `li` table that is mapped by *ORM* (*Hibernate*) in the following `Li` class:
    package a.b;
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "li", schema = "public")
    @TypeDef(name="inet", typeClass=InetType.class)
    public class Li {

```
    private long id;
    private Date requestTime;
    private String mac;
    private String username;
    private Serializable srcIp;
    private Serializable dstIp;
    private Short length;
    private Short ipProtocol;
    private Integer srcPort;
    private Integer dstPort;

    //..... ... some other related functions (getters, setters, etc)
}
```

Now, for being able to create a criteria query for `Li` entity class, I created its metamodel:

```
package a.metamodel.b;
@StaticMetamodel(Li.class)
public class Li_ {

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Li, Long> id;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Li, Date> requestDate;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Li, String> mac;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Li, String> username;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Li, Serializable> srcIp;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Li, Serializable> dstIp;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Li, Short> length;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Li, Short> ipProtocol;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Li, Integer> srcPort;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Li, Integer> dstPort;

}
```

Because I need to search on `li` table after hour extracted from `requestDate` field, I created the following `postgres` function:

```
create or replace function public.extract_hour(time_param timestamp with time zone) 
    returns double precision language sql as $function$

    SELECT EXTRACT(hour from $1);            
$function$;
```

Until now everithing tested and works great. So I started to create my criteria:

```
EntityManager em = ...
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Li> c = cb.createQuery(Li.class);
Root<Li> l = c.from(Li.class);

//pay attention here
Expression<Double> extractHour = cb.function("extract_hour", Double.class, l.get(Li_.requestDate));
c.where(cb.equal(extractHour, Double.parseDouble(aDynamicHourValue)));
TypedQuery<Li> q = em.createQuery(c);
List<Li> lis = q.getResultList();
```

When I run the code above I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.get(AbstractPathImpl.java:146)
    ...............
```

of course, that error comes from that line:

```
Expression<Double> extractHour = cb.function("extract_hour", Double.class, l.get(Li_.requestDate));
```

Can anybody help me on solving that issue?

Comment: c.from(Li.class); // is returning null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem with my criteria query was the fact that I put `Li` entity in a package, and its metamodel `Li_` on another package. I moved `Li_` on the same package with `Li` and now it seems that this issue is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but, in your entity the field is named `requestTime` but in your MetaModel you named it `requestDate`. I think that MetaModel works with Introspection so maybe your error comes from that Hibernate cannot locate the field named `requestDate` as it does not exists.